# IntelliJ IDEA CE confliction issue between Android SDK and JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, sdk

I recently installed IntelliJ IDEA CE on my Mac. Now IntelliJ doesn't comes with Android SDK or JDK by default, so IntelliJ asked me to first setup a Java JDK then setup Android SDK. Now I also have Android Studio installed on my Mac, now since Android Studio comes by default with Android SDK and Open JDK, I didn't took the pain to download Android SDK and JDK again so I simply set the path to Android Studio's JDK and Android SDK for IntelliJ so my question is will this result in any confliction between Android Studio and IntelliJ?

Comment: Should work fine with the same JDK/Android SDK.

Comment: so that answers my question